# List to string and for loop

Tags: python

How do I take a list and get each value in it used, trying to create a URL for each value in the list?

I've tried the below as well but it doesn't take each list item/value individually..

```
sampleguid.append(allguid[1:5])

for guid in sampleguid:
  full_url = url + "?" + str(sampleguid[0])
  print full_url
```

I didn' t realize it before but there's also some unneeded characters in the list ie quotes, commas, brackets - how do I remove those?

What happens right now when I run

```
for guid in sampleguid:
  full_url = url + "?" + str(guid)
  print full_url
```

Is that it prints out:

```
 url?['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']
```

Where what I want is:

```
url?value1
url?value2
url?value3
url?value4
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `full_url = url + "?" + guid`?

Comment: As it stands, you use the **first element in `sampleguid`** every time.

Comment: @vaultah that results in TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Can you give an example of values with unneeded characters and then the intended result? Is it the case that it is possible that there is `guid="value1()"` and you want to use only `guid="value1"`?

Comment: clarified the question a bit

Comment: I editted my answer for the second time. Is the part after the question mark always in  python-list-like format? Or can it also be more general like `url?x,y,z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sampleguid[0]` it means that you use the same value in each row, i.e. the first item in the list `sampleguid`.

The change you are looking for is

```
sampleguid.append(allguid[1:5])

# for each item, let's call it guid, in the list sampleguid
# do the following
for guid in sampleguid:
  full_url = url + "?" + str(guid)
  print full_url
```

If you use **Python 3.x**, then you can use even following one-liner:

```
print(*(url + "?" + str(guid) for guid in sampleguid), sep="\n")
```

For **Python 2.x**, you can also use following:

```
print "\n".join((url + "?" + str(guid) for guid in sampleguid))
```

The two one-liner examples are rather for fun here. The first code is probably much more understandable.

**EDIT (unneeded characters):**

If I understood well your intention with unneeded characters, then this could work for you. It is not an elegant solution, but it can do.

```
sampleguid.append(allguid[1:5])

# for each item, let's call it guid, in the list sampleguid
# do the following
for guid in sampleguid:
    # list of unneeded characters you want to remove
    unneeded_chars = ['"','(',')',"'"]
    splitter_char = ","
    for c in unneeded_chars:
        guid = guid.replace(c,splitter_char)
    for guid_item in guid:
        full_url = url + "?" + str(guid_item)
        print full_url
```

It first replaces all unneeded characters by a special "splitter" character. Then you split the string by the "splitter" character and then you repeat the same thing as before for each specified substring.

Comment: excellent - thx, I didn' t realize it before but there's also some unneeded characters in the list ie quotes, commas, brackets - how do I remove those?

Comment: please, update your question and give a few examples of quotes, commas etc you want to remove... i will then edit my answer

Comment: @Marek the "unneeded characters" OP was referring to is actually the representation of a list - he has a list of lists, not just a list of items. There's no need to remove those characters, as they're not relevant. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29520828/1426065) for the solution.

Comment: @MattDMo Even after the clarification, I understand that it can also happen that the printed line in the previous case could also be something like `url?x,y,z' and the intention is to get `url?x`, `url?y` and `url?z` on three lines instead. I guess that the example @Tony chose was not the best example and that the problem is more general than just "list of lists".

Answer (score 0):

You're always accessing `sampleguid[0]`, which is the first item in the list. You probably want something more like this:

```
sampleguid.append(allguid[1:5])

for guid in sampleguid:
  full_url = url + "?" + str(guid)
  print full_url
```

This will operate on each item in the list, rather than just the first with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated question, you actually have a list of lists you're trying to iterate over. The following should work:

```
for guid in sampleguid:
    for item in guid:
        full_url = url + "?" + str(item)
        print full_url
```

First, you grab each sublist (`guid`) from the master list `sampleguid`. Then, you iterate over `guid` to get each `item` in it, generate the URL, and print it.